# Minikube Kubernetes won't allow ingress on Mac despite running as a VM

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I ran `minikube start --vm=true` which output:

```
  minikube v1.12.2 on Darwin 10.15.5
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
❗  Your system has 16384MB memory but Docker has only 1991MB. For a better performance increase to at least 3GB.

    Docker for Desktop  > Settings > Resources > Memory


  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.8 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: dashboard, default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

And then this `minikube addons enable ingress` which got me this error:

```
  Due to docker networking limitations on darwin, ingress addon is not supported for this driver.
Alternatively to use this addon you can use a vm-based driver:

    'minikube start --vm=true'

To track the update on this work in progress feature please check:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332
```

But I ran minikube with that specific flag - any suggestions?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It looks like your **Minikube** is not running as a VM. Actually it still uses **Docker** driver. Just take a closer look at the output, where `Docker` is mentioned a few times:

```
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
❗  Your system has 16384MB memory but Docker has only 1991MB. For a better performance increase to at least 3GB.

    Docker for Desktop  > Settings > Resources > Memory
```

Where the key point is *"based on existing profile"*

and here:

```
  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.8 ...
```

Although you're trying to start your **Minikube** with `--vm=true` option, it's apparently ignored and your default settings are used.

Most probably it happens because first time you ran it with `--driver=docker` option (either explicitly or implicitly) and it has been saved in your **Minikube** profile. To fix this you will probably need to remove your **Minikube** instance and then start it again with `--vm=true` option. You can be even more scecific and choose the exact hypervisor by providing `--driver=hyperkit` option.

So, simply try to start your **Minikube** this way:

```
minikube start --vm=true --driver=hyperkit
```

If this doesn't help and you'll see again the same output, mentioning that it is using `docker` driver all the time, run:

```
minikube stop && minikube delete && minikube start --vm=true --driver=hyperkit
```

This should resolve your issue. Once it starts using **HyperKit** hypervisor, you should be able to run `minikube addons enable ingress` without any errors.

Comment: please add a warning for M1 macbooks, this just deletes your minikube so you have to start all over again as the hyperkit isn't supported by ARM.